# Chrome plugin that auto-pauses download when system enters sleep mode

Tags: chrome, download-manager

I'm looking for a Chrome extension that will automatically pause all active downloads when the system goes into sleep mode (such as when I close my laptop lid).  I currently use [DownloadAll](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/downloadall/ajffocjdcmpgjmdfdfkdfdbkjafbkcke?hl=en), which is certainly a lovely piece of software - but it doesn't (that I've been able to find) have a way to pause downloads automatically.  There is nothing I hate more than being in the middle of a sizable download and forgetting to pause it when I put my laptop in sleep mode to go to bed/class/whatever.

Requirements:

1. Freeware
2. Works on the newest Windows (7) version of Chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Free Download Manager](http://www.freedownloadmanager.org/) has a [chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/free-download-manager-chr/ahmpjcflkgiildlgicmcieglgoilbfdp?hl=en), is freeware and works with Windows 7. However, it requires you to also install the client software on the PC in order to function.

It also has the ability to resume broken downloads even after a system standby or restart